# Testing in-app billing before releasing a new version of an application

Tags: android, integration-testing, google-play, in-app-billing, android-permissions

I have a [free application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zighinetto.wifitav) in which I want to add a premium product.

I'm developing the new code while maintaining the older version for bugfixes. Now I would like to test IAB integration at least with my personal phone (not the best idea), but Google Play doesn't allow me to add in-app products until I add the `BILLING` permission, and in fact the currently *release* version doesn't.

The question comes straightforward: how can I add in-app products before releasing a new version of the application? If I must add the `BILLING` (and also the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`) permission before implementing the premium feature I fear that users won't receive timely bugfixes to their installed versions, as soon as they have auto update enabled of course.

Do you have any ideas to suggest?

Comment: will you give me some hint how you implement in app billing

Comment: Almost cloned from Google's example (v3 API), then with a wrapper class that eases invocation from my UI. I'm not hiding things for security by obscurity, I don't get the point of your question

Comment: i am applying in app billing but donot get proper solution to implement in app biling in my application

Comment: I think you should search tutorials, search stackoverflow and ultimately post a new **question**. IAB is complex matter to be answered in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add In-App products before version release, you must upload an APK of your application with BILLING permission. Use the "advance mode" of the upload APK page form in Android Developer Console. ¡Be careful! Just upload it, don't publish it!

Once you've done that, you will be able to add products from the "In-App products" page of yout application in the ADC.